# Func vs. Action vs. Predicate

Tags: c#, delegates, action, func

With real examples and their use, can someone please help me understand:

1. When do we need a [`Func<T, ..>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=netcore-3.1) delegate?
2. When do we need an [`Action<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netcore-3.1) delegate?
3. When do we need a [`Predicate<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netcore-3.1) delegate?

Comment: Even though this is a duplicate it has a more thorough accepted answer

Comment: @reggaeguitar What's interesting is that both of the accepted answer is from Jon Skeet

Comment: Reading Jon Skeet's book C# in Depth brought me here.  Talk about inception.

Answer (score 1078, accepted):

The difference between `Func` and `Action` is simply whether you want the delegate to return a value (use `Func`) or not (use `Action`).

`Func` is probably most commonly used in LINQ - for example in projections:

```
 list.Select(x => x.SomeProperty)
```

or filtering:

```
 list.Where(x => x.SomeValue == someOtherValue)
```

or key selection:

```
 list.Join(otherList, x => x.FirstKey, y => y.SecondKey, ...)
```

`Action` is more commonly used for things like `List<T>.ForEach`: execute the given action for each item in the list. I use this less often than `Func`, although I *do* sometimes use the parameterless version for things like `Control.BeginInvoke` and `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.

`Predicate` is just a special cased `Func<T, bool>` really, introduced before all of the `Func` and most of the `Action` delegates came along. I suspect that if we'd already had `Func` and `Action` in their various guises, `Predicate` wouldn't have been introduced... although it *does* impart a certain meaning to the use of the delegate, whereas `Func` and `Action` are used for widely disparate purposes.

`Predicate` is mostly used in `List<T>` for methods like `FindAll` and `RemoveAll`.

Comment: I rather like seeing `Predicate` in a function signature.  It illustrates that the passed method makes a decision rather than just returns a success code or a different sort of `bool`.

Comment: Is there any design guideline on whether to prefer `Predicate<T>` or `Func<T,bool>`? I like the expressiveness of `Predicate`, but I've seen recommendations for `Func` too.

Comment: @Ron: Yes, that's pretty much what my penultimate paragraph was about.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Not that I've seen. LINQ uses `Func` throughout, but that's probably for consistency given that many method accepting a `Func<T,bool>` as a predicate also have an overload taking a `Func<T,int,bool>` for an indexed predicate.

Comment: i kind'a like how simple you have explained it.

func - returns
action - performs (method)

Comment: Who tought it would be useful to have 3 different name for the same thing? It's just a **function pointer**!

Comment: @JonSkeet, Yes, but your second-to-last paragraph reads like a history of how things went down, hiding that intent in the middle of it and making it look like an off-comment. @Ron's comment is clear in that it's a desirable effect (not just a byproduct of software evolution), and makes the point that an intentional choice may be made to use `Predicate`s in some use-cases and `Func<…,bool>`s in others to convey meaning. _Coincidentally, one could say that the difference between your penultimate paragraph and @Ron's comment is like the difference between using `Func<T,bool>` and `Predicate<T>`._

Comment: For what it's worth, in C++ the notion of predicate also means that the function is assumed to be a "pure function", i.e. it should always produce the same result if given the same input, while simple functions-producing-bools do not give such a guarantee.

Of course, this is not enforced by the compiler or anything, but explicitly stating that a function parameter is a "predicate" helps documenting this sort of assumption (which can be rather important in some contexts, e.g. for multithreading).

Comment: Note that Linq (or really overload resolution of both C# and VB) will allow a `Func<T,bool>` where it needs a `Predicate<T>` **but not vice versa:** "cannot convert from 'System.Predicate<int>' to 'System.Func<int, bool>'".

Comment: This means that if you create a `Where<T>(this s, Predicate p)` extension method for the handful of cases where you already have a `Predicate` to use in a `Where` clause, suddenly all your `Where` clauses match this new extension method (including the one now recursively used internally expecting it to continue to refer to the existing `Where` extension method :-( ).

Comment: @MarkHurd: I'd have to see the exact situation to understand why overload resolution is behaving in that way. Note that there's a big difference between a lambda expression which can be converted to either a `Func<T, bool>` or a `Predicate<T>`, and a reference to an existing `Predicate<T>`. To call the original extension method, just call it as a static method: `Enumerable.Where(...)`

Comment: Part of what I noticed is specific to VB.NET: as far as I can tell there's no equivalent in C# for `Dim IsEven = Function(x As Integer) ((x And 1) = 0)`. The equivalent `var IsEven = (int x) => ((x & 1) == 0);` complains: "Cannot assign lambda expression to an implicitly-typed local variable".

Comment: @MarkHurd: It looks like VB creates a new delegate type for situations like that.

Comment: And it means `queryable.Where(IsEven)` is only `IEnumerable` using the Linq-provided `.Where` extensions, but when I provide my own `Predicate` based ones (one for `IEnumerable` and one for `IQueryable`) it is `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 476):

**Action** is a delegate (pointer) to a method, that takes zero, one or more input parameters, but does not return anything.

**Func** is a delegate (pointer) to a method, that takes zero, one or more input parameters, and returns a value (or reference).

**Predicate** is a special kind of Func often used for comparisons (takes a generic parameter and returns bool).

Though widely used with Linq, Action and Func are concepts logically independent of Linq. C++ already contained the basic concept in form of typed function pointers.

Here is a small example for Action and Func without using Linq:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action<int> myAction = new Action<int>(DoSomething);
        myAction(123);           // Prints out "123"
                                 // can be also called as myAction.Invoke(123);

        Func<int, double> myFunc = new Func<int, double>(CalculateSomething);
        Console.WriteLine(myFunc(5));   // Prints out "2.5"
    }

    static void DoSomething(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }

    static double CalculateSomething(int i)
    {
        return (double)i/2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Predicate is a delegate that takes generic parameters and returns bool

Comment: Nice example! Note that you can also invoke myAction by simply calling it: `myAction(123);`. You don't need to use `.Invoke()`

Comment: and just for completeness if you want to use Func which takes no parameters but returns value (or reference) you should write something like this *Func<double> myFoo = new Func<double>(foo);* and foo definition could be **static double foo(){return 1.0;}**

Comment: @Martin Predicate only takes one parameter.

Answer (score 68):

**Func** - When you want a delegate for a function that may or may not take parameters and returns a value. The most common example would be Select from LINQ:

```
var result = someCollection.Select( x => new { x.Name, x.Address });
```

**Action** - When you want a delegate for a function that may or may not take parameters and does not return a value. I use these often for anonymous event handlers:

```
button1.Click += (sender, e) => { /* Do Some Work */ }
```

**Predicate** -  When you want a specialized version of a Func that evaluates a value against a set of criteria and returns a boolean result (true for a match, false otherwise). <strike>Again, these are used in LINQ quite frequently for things like Where:</strike>

```
var filteredResults = 
    someCollection.Where(x => x.someCriteriaHolder == someCriteria);
```

I just double checked and it turns out that LINQ doesn't use Predicates. Not sure why they made that decision...but theoretically it is still a situation where a Predicate would fit.

Comment: I know this is old, but Predicate was not used by LINQ because it predates the Func and Action that we know today, and the latter two can be used to achieve the exact same result in a much better way.

Comment: @gparent, why is it better? I think the readability is better when meaningfully-named delegates are used instead of `Func` or `Action`.

Comment: It depends how you use delegates, but sometimes the name isn't so important and having to create functions and variables just for one use to me decreases readability.