# C# error when using explicitly defined Predicate

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, predicate

i have a number of lambda expressions that will be using the same predicate in a where clause. As such i am using the predicate type for the first time. Here is what i have..

```
Predicate<Type> datePredicate = o => o.Date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

When i use it in my query (below), i am getting the following error..

Error:

```
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,bool>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Usage:

```
Type t = collection.Where(datePredicate).SingleOrDefault();
```

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: How is your collection defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Func<MyObject, bool> datePredicate = (o => o.Date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));

collection.Where(datepredicate);
```

Also when you're doing `.SingleOrDefault()`, not sure how that will magically turn into a `Type` since your `List<T>` is not a `List<Type>` as far as I know (since `Type` doesn't have a `Date` property).

Comment: thanks Josh your answer worked. can you tell me why i needed to use a Func and not a Predicate?

Comment: This S/O question might provide some enlightenment:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317479/func-vs-action-vs-predicate

Comment: Just because `.Where` expects a `Func<T, bool>`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot statically figure out what `Type` your `o` parameter is. I would presume `o` is of type `DateTime`. Compilers don't make presumptions :)

```
Predicate<DateTime> datePredicate = o => o.Date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

Try that.

Comment: I fixed my answer up - I think you edited your question while I was answering first.