# Fluent NHibernate: returning rows in Dictionaries

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to retrieve a Dictionary as a return value from a query, and
I haven't had much luck with the following:

```
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("SELECT Email, COUNT(Id) as IdCount FROM AccountDataModel WHERE Email = :Email")
                        .SetParameter(":Email", model.Email); 

IList<T> list = query.List<T>();

IDictionary<string, object> data = list.ToDictionary<string, object>(x => x); //Error, no method argument matches.
```

The ToDictionary method asks for a type of Func. I found a definition for Func, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317479/func-vs-action-vs-predicate).

After seeing this, I tried the following:

```
list.ToDictionary<string, object>(y => y.As<string>().As<object>());
```

I receive an error in the process...

Is there a straight way to do this, or is it more of a hacky methodology which promotes it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to substitute the actual parametertype in the place of Generic typeParameter `T` in the code `IList<T> list = query.List<T>();`

something like `IList<Email> list = query.List<Email>();`

Then when you are calling the `ToDictionary` specify the key for it.ie..
`IDictionary<string, Email> data = list.ToDictionary(x => x.emailId);`

Comment: Email is not an object though; it's a string.

Comment: You need to have an Nhibernate session object which maps to the query result.