# C# creating function queue

Tags: c#, .net, queue, action, func

I have written a class called QueueManager:

```
class QueueManager
{
    Queue functionsQueue;

    public bool IsEmpty 
    { 
        get 
            {
                if (functionsQueue.Count == 0)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
    }

    public QueueManager()
    {
        functionsQueue = new Queue();
    }

    public bool Contains(Action action)
    {
        if (functionsQueue.Contains(action))
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }

    public Action Pop()
    {
        return functionsQueue.Dequeue() as Action;
    }

    public void Add(Action function)
    {
        functionsQueue.Enqueue(function);
    }

    public void Add(Func<CacheObject,Boolean> function)
    {
        functionsQueue.Enqueue(function);
    }
```

and when I create an instance of this class and call Add method it works fine for functions with no arguments, for example:
 functionQueue.Add(Method); , but when calling on methods that have an argument and return value(in my case ClassType as argument, and Boolean as return value), for  example functionQueue.Add(Method2(classObject)); it does not compile, what am I missing?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317479/func-vs-action-vs-predicate

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because with `functionQueue.Add(Method2(classObject))` you queue the result of your call, not the call itself.

To enqueue a method with parameters you should change the `Add` prototype to accept parameters (and store them together with the delegate). As alternative you can use lambdas:

```
functionQueue.Add(() => Method2(classObject));
```

(then your second overload of `Add` is useless, you can always queue an `Action` where you give all the parameters inside the closure).

**Update**
An example of a queue of this type is inside WinForms, dispatching of methods from other threads than the main thread is done with a *method queue* (look at the disassembly of `Control.MarshaledInvoke`). Skipping synchronization and contexts it keeps a `System.Collections.Queue` where each entry is `ThreadMethodEntry` (a structure used to hold needed data).

Comment: Wow..that actually makes sense..aaand it works :D.. thanks :D