# Why does Linq require Func<T,bool> and not Predicate<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've been calling the following Linq method:

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate
)
```

I'm wondering why Linq doesn't accept the perfectly good `System.Predicate<T>` instead of, or as well as, `Func<T,bool>`.

Is this a deliberate Linq style/design decision? Or am I missing something obvious about `Func` and `Predicate`?

Comment: No one loves `Predicate<T>`... it is the forgotten child :-)

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317479/func-vs-action-vs-predicate

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering why Linq doesn't accept the perfectly good
>   System.Predicate

Because they are semantically equivalent. There is no reason to take two overloads which do exactly the same. The advantage of (IMO) with `Func` is that it has several overloads taking more input types and returning any output type, while `Predicate<T>` is very limited.