# How do i modify a role's hex colour with a bot using ModifyAsync?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm using Visual Studio and Discord.Net v2.1.1.

I've searched all over, but nothing I've found shows me a way to be able to modify a role's colour (or `IRole`).

Is there any other way to do this? What am I doing wrong?

`Context.Guild.GetRole(roleid).ModifyAsync(???);`

**edit:** this worked for me: `await Context.Guild.GetRole(roleid).ModifyAsync(x => x.Color = new Color(1, 4, 150));`

Comment: https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/blob/release/1.0.2/src/Discord.Net.Core/Entities/Roles/RoleProperties.cs#L4

Comment: For future reference, this is actually documented in the respective `XProperties` documentation, in this case, [RoleProperties](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.RoleProperties.html)

Answer (score 2):

### Short Answer

In Discord.Net, most if not all `ModifyAsync` takes an `Action<T>` as its parameter, and its documentation and such usage is in its respective `XProperties` documentation. In this case, [RoleProperties](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.RoleProperties.html).

[image]

### Long Answer

Since these methods all take an `Action<T>`, we can take a look at what [Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1) is on [Microsoft .NET API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/). From the documentation, we learn that it is a delegate, and the easiest way to make a delegate is with a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) (also see [Func vs. Action vs. Predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317479/func-vs-action-vs-predicate)).

From this, we can come up the following,

```
var role = guild.GetRole(id);
await role.ModifyAsync(role =>
{
    // Assign the color to a new Discord.Color struct of color [123, 123, 123]
    role.Color = new Color(123, 123, 123);
});
```

All `ModifyAsync`s work more or less the same.